# Trigger executes first than function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. My current code doesn't get the data until a change occurs in the select element. That's why I'm trying to force the select when the tab is changed (because my .change function needs a parameter from `selectorMRPC();`. But my code somehow the `$('#selectMRPC').trigger('change');` executes first than `selectorMRPC();` and I get error of mrpc undefined even tho the .trigger is after the function `selectorMRPC();`

How can I force a update on the selector for the first item?? It needs to be triggered after I run the function `selectorMRPC();`

```
  function selectorMRPC() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'IndividualSimulator',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#selectMRPC').empty();
            JSON.parse(result).forEach(function (mrpc) {
                var option = $('<option>', {
                    value: mrpc.name,
                    text: mrpc.name
                });

                //Persist data with option
                option.data('mrpc', mrpc);
                console.log(mrpc);

                $('#selectMRPC').append(option);
            });
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
    return false;
}


   //Execute MRPC
$('#runMRPC').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get data
    var data = $('#mrpcData').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'jdbcMRPC',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            //Change to result tab
            showResult(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            showError(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});


$('#selectMRPC').change(function () {
    //fetch data
    var mrpc = $(this).find('option:selected').data('mrpc');

    $('#paramBody').empty();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var field = mrpc["field" + i];

        if (field !== undefined) {
            var parsedField = field.split('_');
            var value = parsedField[0];
            var type = parsedField[1];

            switch (type) {
                case  "S":
                    type = "text";
                    if (value === '""')
                        value = null;
                    break;
                case "B":
                    type = "checkbox";
                    break;
                case "N":
                    type = "number";
                    value = parseInt(value);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    type = "number";
                    value = parseInt(value);
                    if (value === '""')
                        value = null;
                    break;
            }
            //else use checkbox
            if(type === "checkbox")
            {
                $('#paramBody').append('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + type + '</td><td><div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">' +
                    '<input class="text-center" id="field'+i+'" name="Fields" type="checkbox" value="' +value + '"><label for="field'+i+'"></label></div></tr>');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#paramBody').append('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + type + '</td><td><input class="text-center" name="Fields" type="' + type + '" value="' +value + '"></tr>');
            }
        }
    }
});


  $(".next-step").click(function (e) {

    var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
    $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
    nextTab($active);

    //if it's the second tab, refresh it
    var liID = $('#menu').find('.active').attr('id');
    if(liID === "parametersTab") {
        $("#selectMRPC").val($("#selectMRPC option:first").val());
        selectorMRPC();
        $('#selectMRPC').trigger('change');
    }

});
```

Comment: The easy way would be to move `$('#selectMRPC').trigger('change');` into the ajax function after `$('#selectMRPC').append(option);` Alternatively, you can listen for when the data comes back from the ajax request and then execute the line of code but this is a little bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

you can return result of $.ajax from selectorMRPC and then in

```
selectorMRPC().then(function(){
    $('#selectMRPC').trigger('change');
});
```

or use callback function if the trigger is still before select is populated

```
selectorMRPC(function(){
    $('#selectMRPC').trigger('change');
});
```